# Where should the leads go to this kind of DC motor?

Tags: soldering, dc-motor

I've recently bought a couple of small DC motors (Motraxx XDrive 2025-02). However, I'm not sure where to solder the leads to, since the motor doesn't have the usual connectors. Here's how the motor looks like:

[image: side]

[image: back, upside-down]

[image: back, right-side-up]

I'm guessing they should go to the same place where the capacitor (?) is connected, but like I said, I'm not sure. Is my thinking correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep, the capacitor is connected across the motor leads. Just solder to them.

Specifically, the capacitor across the motor leads is there to reduce EMF produced by the motor. Basically, a DC motor looks like an inductor. Since the current has to flow through brushes, which are not in continuous contact, every time the brushes break contact, you get a high-voltage pulse as the motor's magnetic field collapses. The capacitor helps reduce the extremely high frequency component of these pulses.

Comment: In the absence of a cap, to what extent would inductive flyback pulses reach the brushes?  I would expect that caps mounted to the armature could greatly reduce flyback nastiness, but otherwise my intuition would suggest that the cap helps reduce the harmonic content of the current waveform that would result from the scallop-shaped back-EMF waveform of a three-phase motor.

Comment: A very comprehensive answer. Thanks for the description of the capacitor's use.

Comment: @supercat - What I mean is basically as the motor rotates, the brushes are making and breaking contact with the rotor (which is inductive). Basically, every time the connection is lost (as the brushes slide along the commutator), you get a high-voltage pulse that is dumped onto whatever is driving the motor when the brush resumes contact. This is a very different reason from why you would put caps across a AC/three-phase motor (which has no brushes). The cap is probably very small too (I think the radio controlled car I had a long time ago used ~47 pF).

Comment: @FakeName: If a rotating 3-phase motor is viewed as three low-impedance AC generators wired together, and one connects such a thing to a rigid voltage source, the current waveforms produced would be rather nasty even if (especially if) the motor had no inductance.  If the commutators didn't switch at precisely optimal tiles, this could make things particularly bad.  I generally see the caps on what I believe to be high-speed low-torque motors which I would expect to have comparatively low inductance, hence by question on whether the problem is current switching or voltage switching.